# user authentication and authorization. Displaying only looged user profile

Tags: node.js, express

I am having an issue with user authentication aftre sign in. This is part of expanding my knowledge and now I am stuck with this.

My code looks like this:

Route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* import controllers */
const {
  findById,
  isAuth,
  isAdmin,
} = require('../controllers/user.controller.js');
const { requierSignin } = require('../controllers/auth.controller.js');

router.param('userId', findById);

router.get('/test/:userId', requierSignin, isAuth, findById, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ user: req.profile });
});
```

Here i have sign in, find user by id and my authorization method. This is a test route.
As i goes for my controllers:
User:

```
const User = require('../models/user.models');

//user middleware
exports.findById = async (req, res, next, id) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findById(id).exec();
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        errors: [
          {
            msg: 'User not found',
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    req.profile = user; // this will get user profile based on User
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
};

/* check if user is authenticated */
exports.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  /* id we have user that will send id and is auth */
  let user = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id;

  console.log(req.profile);
  console.log('auth', req.auth);
  console.log('id', req.profile._id);
  console.log('user', user);
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      errors: [
        {
          msg: 'Access Denied',
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

and my sign in method from auth.controller

```
const config = require('config');

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); //generate token
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt'); //auth check

const User = require('../models/user.models');
const secret = config.get('jwtSecret');

exports.requierSignin = expressJwt({
  secret,
  userProperpty: 'auth',
});
```

This is only part of that code but if rest will be neede I will update it
As far i get. User sign in and the getting a profile is working. Bu I want to protect other user profiles with isAuth. This is getting me "Access denied". From console log i got

```
auth undefined
id 5eaac004200b95869cc76531
user undefined
GET /api/test/5eaac004200b95869cc76531 403 88.591 ms - 36
```

But when i change in my isAuth method user to be only:

```
let user = req.profile
```

user is defined.

Not sure what I am missing here :/ Not sure why i don't get in my 'auth' ._id and this is causing issues

[github repo](https://github.com/shivetay/udemy_React_Node_Ecommerce)

Comment: What is the ( ```console.log(id)``` ) id arg value on start of ```findById``` call?

Comment: hi. I put a consol.log(req.profile._id) and i get user id user_control 5ea918f06f418e5e64184215. this is the same id that i put in my /:userId
and from the beginig hen i console log i get id 5ea918f06f418e5e64184215
with no authorization i do get user profile, but i want to display only logged user profila to user. So user JOhn can't display full user Tom profile

Comment: id from findById 5ea918f06f418e5e64184215
id after req.profile = user 5ea918f06f418e5e64184215
profil {
  role: 1,
  history: [],
  _id: 5ea918f06f418e5e64184215,
  name: 'testowy10',
  email: 'testowy10@mail.com',
  salt: '1b2d2d5d-f662-4664-bb09-48d57745e34b',
  hash_password: '50d8f92f376c1cf12aeff2cab8d9e6f2d680a8f9',
  date: 2020-04-29T06:04:32.149Z,
  createdAt: 2020-04-29T06:04:32.154Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-04-29T06:04:32.154Z,
  __v: 0
}
auth { iat: 1588443537 }
auth undefined
id 5ea918f06f418e5e64184215
user false
GET /api/test/5ea918f06f418e5e64184215 403

Answer (score 0):

Got this working

Issue was in my user sign in method:

```
const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user._id,
        email: user.email,
        name: user.name,
        role: user.role,
      },
    };
    return res.json({
      token,
      payload,
    });
```

In my payload i sending

```
id:user._id
```

But when i generted a token i was doing sending id

```
// generate a token with id and secret
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: _id }, secretJwt);
```

So every time when myt prtected rout was checking id from token and user

```
 let user = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id;
```

This was false as there was no id to compare. 
Setting _id to id solved my issue

```
// generate a token with id and secret
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: _id }, secretJwt);
```

That was a brain cracker for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even I'm facing the same issue using "postman", as "req.profile" property has to be set from frontend only if the user is "signedIn"

```
req.profile = user
```

> so we need to populate the user first

```
exports.setUserInfo = function setUserInfo(request) {
  const getUserInfo = {
    _id: request._id,
    firstName: request.profile.firstName,
    lastName: request.profile.lastName,
    email: request.email,
    role: request.role
  };

  return getUserInfo;
};
```

> git repo https://github.com/NRSingh007/mern-starter/blob/master/server/helpers.js

Comment: is the link to the repo realy necessary ?

Comment: The code is there in that repo. Go ahead and check.
And if you have a more simple and better solution then please feel free to answer, so that it will be helpful to all. Thanks